# Client Side Validations on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, heroku, jquery-validate, client-side-validation

I am using https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations to validate my sign up form.

I am validating the uniqueness of username and email in that form:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :username, :email, :case_sensitive => false
```

The database validations for uniqueness are taking place fine on my local machine. But when I try them on Heroku, they do not work.

Edit:

Here is the sign up form (I am using devise):

```
<%= form_for @user, :as => :user, :validate => true, :url => user_registration_path do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.label :name, :class => "signupin-label span-2" %><%= f.text_field :name, :class => "signupin-field last", :autocomplete => "off"%></div>
    <div><%= f.label :username, :class => "signupin-label span-2" %><%= f.text_field :username, :class => "signupin-field last", :autocomplete => "off" %></div>
    <div><%= f.label :email, :class => "signupin-label span-2" %><%= f.text_field :email, :class => "signupin-field last", :autocomplete => "off" %></div>
    <div><%= f.label :password, :class => "signupin-label span-2" %><%= f.password_field :password, :class => "signupin-field last", :autocomplete => "off" %></div>
    <div class="signupin-bl"><%= f.submit "Sign up", :id => "signUpButton"  %></div>
<% end %>
```

I am getting following error:

rails.validations.js:154

Uncaught TypeError: Object (?-mix:^(a-zA-Z**?|*([a-zA-Z0-9]+_?)*)$) has no method 'test'

Can someone please guide?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you look in a web inspector to see if any requests to the server is being sent and just not received by Heroku? I would bet the problem with this is in Javascript land and not in Rails.

Comment: Thanks hornairs: Here is the error that I get in inspector: Uncaught TypeError: Object (?-mix:^([a-zA-Z](_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*_?|_([a-zA-Z0-9]+_?)*)$) has no method 'test' (in rails.validations.js) and http://myapp.heroku.com/validators/uniqueness.json?case_sensitive=false&user%5Bemail%5D= 404 (Not Found)

Comment: would it be possible to share the app publicly? I can take a look.

Comment: hi bcardarella: The app is currently in private, so unfortunately, I wont be able to share it. However, I have updated the question with more details about the sign up form. Please let me know if you want any more info. Thanks!

Comment: Hi. I found the issue. I was not validating the format of username on the client side and that was causing this error. Thanks for your help.

Comment: neology if you found an issue - please close the question, let's keep things in order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was not validating the format of username on the client side and that was causing this error. Thanks for your help.